# Query to undefined location because of value-binding to object?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've got a controller like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  currentTrack: {'https://cdn.clougfront.com/superimage.jpg'}
})
```

and a template-file like this:

```
<div class="song">
  <img {{bind-attr src=currentTrack.artwork_url}} />
</div>
```

For some reason this causes Ember to send a HTTP-request to http://localhost:4200/undefined . It doesn't happen when currentTrack is just a string.

How can I prevent that but still us currentTrack as an object (it normally has more attributes. I just left them out for the sake of simplicity)?